# How to reuse calculated field without subqueries but with group by

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Suppose I have a table1 with the field item_id
The query

```
select item_id + 1 as num1, (select num1) + 1 as num2 from table1
```

works, but the query

```
select count(*) as num1, item_id, (select num1) + 1 as num2 from table1 group by item_id
```

fails with Error Code: 1247. Reference 'num1' not supported (reference to group function).

I know I can nest a query which calculates the subtotal, and use that in the outer query, but nesting/temp tables are a pain to deal with using CakePHP. I cannot use user variables (@num1 := count(*)) because I need to reuse the data in the same select statement, and the order of read/writes is undefined. Anyone know of a simple way to get around this?

Comment: What SQL statement do you want to be written in CakePHP syntax?

Comment: @AgRizzo The actual query is farily complex. I know of a couple ways to work around the issues in my question, but they are all messy, which just gets compounded due to the way CakePHP handles temp tables. I'm really just asking this question to make my code more readable

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  num1,
        item_id, 
        num1 + 1 AS num2
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  COUNT(*) AS num1, 
                item_id
            FROM  table1
            GROUP BY  item_id 
      ) AS t;
```

Comment: I specifically mentioned that I'm not looking for an answer using subqueries. For a single calculated field it's not a big deal to do this, but for calculated fields based on other calculated fields, it gets very messy. Thanks for the attempt though.